# Laravel set global variables

Tags: laravel, global-variables, global

How i set global variable in Laravel, I tried below but its not working as expect.

I created the constant files in config.

constants.php

```
return
[
'companyID' => 'Auth::user()->company',
]
```

user.php

```
public static function TEST()
{
 return USER::Where('company',config('constants.companyID'))->get();
 }
```

Comment: Try removing single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `auth()->user()` in config file. Also, the approach is not right. Since `auth()->user()` is a global object, just use this query:

```
public static function test()
{
    return User::where('company', auth()->user()->company)->get();
}
```

You can access `auth()->user()->company` from any class or any view.